# Is any singularity a subgerm of $(\mathbb{C}^n, 0)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, singularity-theory

I am studying singularity theory. I have often come across, in the literature, the sentence which says "let $(X,0) \subset (\mathbb{C}^n,0)$ be a singularity". Here a singularity is a complex space germ.

My question is whether a given singularity $(X,x)$ may always be assumed to be $(X,0) \subset (\mathbb{C}^n,0)$ for some $n$, under an identification of $x$ with the origin $0$.

As far as I understand, by definition every point of a complex space has its neighborhood which is isomorphic to a complex model space as complex analytic ringed space. A complex model space is a complex closed subspace of $(\mathbb{C}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^n})$; hence we may assume that any singularity $(X,x)$ is a subgerm of $(\mathbb{C}^n,0)$.

I would like to know if my understanding is correct or not. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right to me.

Comment: Thank you, Donu!